# Ошибка: already exists in VFS

Tags: maven

Хочу создать многомодульный проект Maven.

pom.xml root:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.nameproject</groupId>
<artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Добавляю новый модуль, artifactId для него устанавливаю nameprojectModule1

Возникает ошибка:

```
Failed to create a Maven project: 'D:/JavaMulti/pom.xml' already exists in VFS
```

Возник вопрос: как правильно создавать многомодульный Maven проект?